# Set hidden input in modal form based on what button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that is laoded into a modal, there is a hidden input in it

```
<input type="hidden" name="transType" id="transType" value="">
```

There are two buttons that can open the form

```
<a href="" id="Buy" class="trigger">Buy</a>
<a href="" id="Sell" class="trigger">Sell</a>
```

I want to set the input#transType value based on what button is clicked, again the form is loaded in a modal and opened when the button is clicked

```
$(function(){
    $('.trigger').click(function(e){
        //modal stuff, good to go
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(link, function(data){
        modal.open({content: data});
        //here is where I need to set the val
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Buy')) {
            $('#transType').val('Buy');
        } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Sell')) {
            $('#transType').val('Sell');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I have it working with 2 separate click handlers, one for each button and setting the value that way, but would like a cleaner function that covers both buttons. How do I switch the hidden input's value based on the ID of the button (same class)?

**SOLUTION**
Thanks for the help guys, got it working. Had to change the construct of the funciton, I wasn't scoping 'this' correctly. Here is the final solution, in case anyone ever runs into this.

```
$(function(){
    $('.trigger').click(function(e){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'Buy') {
            $.get(link, function(data){
                modal.open({content: data});
                $('#transType').val('buy');
            });
        }
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'Sell') {
            $.get(link, function(data){
              modal.open({content: data});
              $('#transType').val('sell');
            });
      }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/kd5ea91a/), the hidden input field (made it visible for showing) will allways have the id's value!

**Code:**
**Jquery:**

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e){
  $('#transType').val($(this).attr('id'));        
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="transType" id="transType" value="">


<a href="#" id="Buy" class="trigger">Buy</a>
<a href="#" id="Sell" class="trigger">Sell</a>
```

---

**SIDENOTE:**

If you want to have a check / different value, you might want to go with this (but I don't see a reason to do this)

```
 $('.trigger').click(function(e){

    if($(this).attr('id') == 'Buy') {
  $('#transType').val($(this).attr('id'));         
    }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'Sell') {
  $('#transType').val($(this).attr('id'));  
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'test') {
  $('#transType').val($(this).attr('id')); 
    }
});
```

Comment: That works, thank you. However, the button ID may not always match the needed value of the hidden input. Thats why I was trying to set it by the ID, with a value I could change.

Comment: So you just go with 2 if statements, not an if/else?

Comment: sorry, edited the answer, that was what I meant. I think the second option is unneccessary if you only want to change by id

Comment: so what I want it to do is like this if($(this).attr('id') == 'Sell'){$('#transType').val('something');}

Comment: The only way I can get it to work is a separate function for each button and explicitly set the value. shit.

Comment: Yeah I see its working on your fiddle, thank you for that. For some reason its getting lost using (this) on my production piece. I can't get it to change the value correctly.

Comment: Here's my example, works in the fiddle not in production for some reason http://jsfiddle.net/jzkfx7u3/2/

Comment: Sure it does break, because this line if($(this).attr('id') == 'Buy') isn't true as you've changed the ID. Try it with the changed it with the first fiddle, this one will always work and appends the IDs value correct to the hidden field

Comment: That was a typo, the line is if($(this).attr('id') == 'BuyBTC') {
        $('#transType').val('Buy');
      }

Comment: I don't get it. Works even on the IPad for me

Comment: Thanks for your help on this @michael, got it working. Had to change the construct of my modal funciton, but you helped lay the groundwork! I really appreciate it, now its exactly like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you are looking for this If I am not wrong!!!
Replace>>

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Buy')) {
$('#transType').val('Buy');
} else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Sell')) {
$('#transType').val('Sell');
}
```

With>>

```
$('#transType').val($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Nope, didn't set the value. I would like to fix what I have as the ID may not match the value I want the input to have. I need to be able to set the hidden input's value based on the button that was clicked ID